# Rutas según lo seleccionado IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Hola buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema resulta que tengo un proyecto en ionic que utiliza tabs, El tab principal muestra:

una lista de hospitales con su dirección de establecimiento:

-hospital del Carmen
 camino rinconada #882

-hospital Sotero del rio
 puente alto #898

Son datos consumido de un Web Service y mostrados con `ng-repeat` y estan contenidos por:

-id_sucursal
-dirección
-nombre_empresa

Explicado esto, al hacer click por ejemplo en el **hospital del Carmen**

Se abre una nueva tabs y Aquí quiero mostrar como titulo su nombre_empresa y utilizar su `id_sucursal` para que me muestre las sucursales que tiene disponible, es decir volver a consumir datos.

Mi código:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="su in sucursales" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/sucursal/{{su.id_sucursal}}">
        <h2>{{su.nombre_empresa}}</h2>
        <p>{{su.direccion}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**app.js:**

```
.state('tab.sucursal', {
    url: '/sucursal/:id_sucursal',
    views: {
        'tab-empresa': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/empresa-sucursal.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Como resultado al hacer click en el nombre de la empresa:

La ruta con su id:

http://localhost:8100/#/tab/sucursal/20

Hasta ahora no eh dado con lo que quiero, mi pregunta es ¿que debo hacer para poder usar el id y así consumir datos, como tambien mostrar el nombre en su titulo?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes definir en tu controlador `$stateParams` como una inyección de dependencia.

```
.controller('TuCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var sucursal = $stateParams.id_sucursal;
})
```

Comment: eso era... grande!

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del `ng-repeat` debes de agregar un enlace en el que vas a manejar el `ui-sref` que haga uso del estado que has creado y envíe el ID de la sucursal a la que ese enlace representa, el código quedaría de esta manera:

```
<div ng-repeat="sucursal in sucursales">
    <a ui-sref="tab.sucursal({id_sucursal:sucursal.id})
       Ver sucursal
    </a>
</div>
```

Esto tendría que funcionar, sino lo que podrías hacer es utilizar el ng-click y en el click enviar el `sucursa.id` y dentro del controlador de la sección podrías hacer `$state.go({id_sucursal:ID_QUE_HA_RECIBIDO_LA_FUNCION})`

Comment: el id ya lo mando y me aparece en la ruta arriba, pero como lo recibo para usarlo?

Comment: eso depende de como tengas definida tus tabs en tu app.js @HernanHumaña

Comment: para recibirlo en el controlador lo que tenes que ahcer es `var id = $stateParams.sucursal_id` eso sería todo